# Unity native plugin function produce NullReferenceException in c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to pass array of 3D float points as reference to a native c function for an advanced calculation. However I get the following error "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

here is the C# script I use to call my native function

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class CppWrapper : MonoBehaviour {

// Use this for initialization
[DllImport ("Unity_Native_Utilities", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern void alignPointSets (ref float[] setA ,ref float[] setB, ref float[] Quaternion);
void Start () {


}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}



void Awake()
{
    int n = 3;
    float[] cSetA = new float[3 * n];
    float[] cSetB = new float[3 * n];
    float[] rotation = new float[4];



    Vector3[] UnitysetA = new Vector3[n];
    Vector3[] UnitysetB = new Vector3[n];


    UnitysetA[0] = new Vector3(0, 0, -1);
    UnitysetA[1] = new Vector3(0, 1, 0);
    UnitysetA[2] = new Vector3(1, 0, 0);

    UnitysetB[0] = new Vector3(0, 1, 0);
    UnitysetB[1] = new Vector3(-1, 0, 0);
    UnitysetB[2] = new Vector3(0, 0, 1);

    convertU2C(ref UnitysetA, ref cSetA);
    convertU2C(ref UnitysetB, ref cSetB);
    alignPointSets (ref cSetA,ref cSetB,ref rotation); //this line produce the error
}
void convertU2C(ref Vector3[] unityArray, ref float[] cArray)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < unityArray.Length; i++)
    {
        cArray[0 + i * 3] = unityArray[i].x;
        cArray[1 + i * 3] = unityArray[i].y;
        cArray[2 + i * 3] = unityArray[i].z;
    }
}
```

}

This is the header file for c interface

```
#ifdef WIN32
 #define INTERFACE_DLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
 #define INTERFACE_DLL_API
#endif
extern "C"
{
INTERFACE_DLL_API void alignPointSets(float*,float* ,float *);
}
```

Comment: in which line the exception is thrown?

Comment: alignPointSets (ref cSetA,ref cSetB,ref rotation); //this line produce the error

Comment: remove the "ref" from the definition of the function, a ref to an array would be a float** on c++, not a float*.

Comment: Thank you it worked as you suggested, but then why did this function worked? convertU2C(ref UnitysetA, ref cSetA); as it is also passing float** and inside I refer the array like this UnitysetA[i]

Comment: wait, convertU2C is a C# function, alignPointSets is a C++ function, that's completely different, your C# function expects a ref float[] and ref Vector3[], so there's nothing wrong with the call, it's like your C++ function were defined to expect a float**.